# Python PhantomJS Sending Keys to Text Field Not Working

Tags: python, phantomjs

So I'm having a weird problem with PhantomJS where it is continually failing to send text to the text input field. When I run my code with a chrome driver, there is no issue, and everything works as expected.

This is the chat box on twitch streams if you were wondering. Here is some code.

```
print("Finding chat box...")
typeKeyword = wait_until_visible_by_xpath('//textarea[@placeholder="Send a message"]', browser)
not_working = True
while not_working:
    try:
        print("Sending keys...")
        typeKeyword.send_keys("hi")
        not_working = False
    except InvalidElementStateException:
        sleep(3)
print("Hitting chat button")
chatButton = wait_until_visible_by_xpath('//button[@class="button send-chat-button primary float-right"]', browser)
chatButton.click()
```

PhantomJS is able to locate the text field, but it keeps getting trapped on the `InvalidElementStateException` when it is checking whether it can send the keys or not. There should be a small delay because the twitch chat box is usually grayed out for 6-10 seconds before it becomes able to type in it. With the chrome driver, after printing "Sending keys..." about 3 times, the code finishes up and the message is typed. With PhantomJS, however, it prints "Sending keys..." forever.

Answer (score 0):

Refind/"refresh" the element inside the loop:

```
while not_working:
    typeKeyword = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//textarea[@placeholder="Send a message"]')
    ...
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try it out :)

Comment: It turns out that adobe flash is needed to type in the chat area. I don't know how to make PhantomJS support flash because I know they took that feature out a while ago. If you have any ideas that would be great!